# Make Terraform ignore the order of list items returned from the service

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm creating an AWS IAM policy that grants access to a resource to a number of remote accounts. I've got these accounts in a list - all good. However when TF checks the current state on the subsequent `plan` it comes back in a different order and TF thinks that it must be corrected. How can I ignore the list order?

This is my resource:

```json
resource "aws_ecr_repository_policy" "repo" {
  policy = jsonencode({
    Statement = [
      {
        Principal = {
          AWS = [ 
              "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:root",
              "arn:aws:iam::567890123456:root",
              "arn:aws:iam::987654321098:root",
          ]
...
```

Now on subsequent `terraform plan` runs I get some variations of this:

```
~ {
    ~ Principal = {
      ~ AWS = [
        + "arn:aws:iam::987654321098:root",    <<< swapped order
          "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:root",
          "arn:aws:iam::567890123456:root",
        - "arn:aws:iam::987654321098:root",    <<< and here
      ]
    }
```

AWS is unpredictable with the order it returns, it changes each time. Can I somehow ignore the order? Ideally without ignoring the whole `policy` block with lifecycle / ignore_changes.

Comment: Probably could use [ignore_changes](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle.html#ignore_changes) to exclude all principles, but it will not limit changes to order only.

Comment: @Marcin how do I do that since the Principals are inside `jsonencode()`?

Comment: This is confusing to me. I have an ECR policy that also explicitly allows certain accounts in our organization as you have here but we don't see any diff churn on reordering accounts. The only difference I see is that ours is just a heredoc with the account IDs statically listed rather than using `jsonencode` (it predates a bunch of fixes/additions to `jsonencode` that allowed for this). If instead you rework the policy to use the [`aws_iam_policy_document` data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_policy_document) does that work?

Comment: same with `aws_iam_policy_document`

Answer (score 4):

This was an issue of terraform-provider-aws (fixed with provider version v4.23.0), see
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/22274

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still getting this with the 4.63.0 AWS provider and `aws_iam_role` resource - principals are reordered each time as in original question.